# What are reasons why the height of the <body> tag wouldn't be related to the height of the <html> tag?

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a website and the `<body>` tag doesn't stretch down the full length of the `<html>` tag. Both have a min-height of 100% and I thought that meant the `<body>` tag would adjust based on what it was embedded in, which is the `<html>` tag. I've been changing values around in firebug to see if it would do anything but no dice.

Basically the height of `<body>` ends up maxing out at 749.4px while the height of `<html>` is 857px.

Any ideas?

Edit: Sorry guys, I got sidetracked after I posted this. Turns out one of the css files changed the body height or something. Basically I ended up just adding "height: 100%;" to the  tag, "min-height: 100%;" to any instance of  and the wrapper class. I'm working with a weird template that the guy before me set up so I got kinda lost haha. I worded the question very strangely, too. If I opened up firebug and mouseovered the html tag it would highlight the whole window but if i highlighted the body tag the overlay would not fit the screen, meaning body was not extending as far as i wanted it to.

Comment: I've noticed that the `<html>` and `<body>` tags are missing from your post. Include them as code.

Comment: Do you have any margins or padding on either of these tags? Some sample code might help too.

Comment: Well, `BODY` is just the body of the document and not the whole document.

Comment: I don't get this question. <html> has nothing to do with your viewport or the display of the document. <body> represents the viewport. <html> is just a structural element, it is never rendered.

Comment: Neither body or HTML "max out" at either of these values, unless you've applied values to them that would cause them to do so.

Answer (score 2):

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

**should work in most scenarios.**

Answer (score 1):

`<html>` tag doesn't have style rules, it doesn't have `width` nor `height`. `<body>` is the parent of them all when it comes to CSS.

Comment: Some browsers (I think older IE versions) use `<html>` as the parent element which means it needs `height: 100%` as well.

Comment: @Marko - I see. But is there any reason not to have `<html>` at `100% x 100%` and work relativeness with the `<body>` tag? It's the same in the end, even easier to work with.